# cmd_vel/Twist Transform Twist Message into Left and Right motor commands

Tags: navigation, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi There,

I have a six wheeled wild thumper that I am using for my final year project for university. I need to transform the linear.x and angular.z velocities into left and right motor commands.

Have you any idea how this is possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209963/cmd_vel/twist-transform-twist-message-into-left-and-right-motor-commands/) by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default wild thumper can not measure its speed, which is required. Did you add encoder to the motors?

You basicly need to transform the linear and angular velocity into speeds for the left and right motors, something  like

```
float speed_wish_right = (cmd_vel.angle*WHEEL_DIST)/2 + cmd_vel.speed;
float speed_wish_left = cmd_vel.speed*2-speed_wish_right;
```

with WHEEL_DIST as the distance between left and right wheels (25.2cm on my wild thumper), cmd_vel.angle is the angular z component and cmd_vel.speed the linear x component.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-27**:
I would personally go for something like the `ros_control` [diff_drive_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller), as that does all these things for you - and more.

Of course, this does not remove the need for encoders, as @Humpelstilzchen already noted.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-05-27**:
Thank you so much for the reply.

I have a motor controller that gives the robot a speed from 0-255 using PWM. Does this count for a measure of the speed? I am although going to be using a camera to estimate the motion using optical flow for odometry.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-05-27**:
This will be very difficult, most ros packages expect that you satisfy their velocity. But if you e.g. just want to teleop it doesn't really matter.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-05-28**:
Oh ok. I dont just need to teleop. I am doing an autonomous 2D mapping robot so i will have to look into this.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-06-02**:
So this example code what units would the speed be in?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-06-02**:
default unit for ros is linear: m/s, angular: rad/s

**Comment by [kwiesz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/23432/kwiesz91/) on 2015-10-26**:
Is that suppose to be "+ cmd_vel.speed" at the end of the first line instead of just "+ cmd_vel"?

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-10-26**:
Im not too sure about that, I landed up using the differential_drive (http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive) package which does it for you.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-10-26**:
kwiesz91: yes, fixed. Basically it is the usual [two-wheel odometry equation](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejohannb/Papers/umbmark.pdf) solved for left and right motor.

Personally, I use this on an AVR so the main CPU doesn't need to calculate the odometry.

**Comment by [Jo_Han_Solo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32380/jo_han_solo/) on 2017-10-26**:
@Humpelstilzchen the distance you're talking about above with the 25.2cm, would that mean that he calculations you are doing would always be in (cm) measurements?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-10-26**:
I do them in m, because I find its always the best do stay with si-units. The equations should work with cm, if you divide the result with 100. Just make sure you always use the same units.

**Comment by [Jo_Han_Solo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32380/jo_han_solo/) on 2017-10-29**:
@Humpelstilzchen thanks for your reply, I ended up doing them in SI units already last week and they seem to work just fine as they are now.